# Navigation missing in Google Analytics when using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

When I use the Chrome web browser, I can't see all the report in Google Analytics because it is missing the left hand navigation column.  In Firefox, I can collapse this column, and then re-open it by clicking on the far left of the screen.  That doesn't work in Chrome.  I can't figure out how to get it back in Chrome.  Has anybody run across this before or know what I should do?

---

### Screenshot in Chrome with missing left hand nav

[image: Google analytics screenshot taken with Chrome having no left hand nav]

---

### Screenshot in Firefox with left hand nav

[image: Google analytics screenshot taken with Firefox with functional left hand nav]

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using and can you try it in a new incognito window with all plugins/extensions disabled?

Comment: Thanks, I submitted the question on the forums there: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/analytics/chrome/analytics/fwvWt55B0aI/vE27ebYuRioJ   I find the community here much more responsive and helpful, so I submitted it here first.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? If so, please add more details like if you already tried in incognito mode, Chrome update channel and version and URLs of both screenshots.

Comment: This is no longer an issue.   I just checked Analytics in Chrom and it looks fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't accidentally collapse the sidebar? It can be toggled off to get it out of the way. Move your cursor over near the left side of your browser window, and there should be a ~15px-wide bar that darkens in color. Click it to reveal the sidebar.

If it really isn't there, next make sure you don't have any addons installed that mess with Analytics in any way; it's possible something's broken. After that if you still have a problem, you might be running into an actual bug and should use the [support channels](http://www.google.com/analytics/support/index.html).

Comment: I get the ~15px-wide bar when it is collapsed in firefox, but nothing at all on the left in chrome.  I've disabled AdBlock and ScriptSafe which are add-ons I use that sometimes cause problems with sites.

Comment: The bar's there for me. I think it's time for you to go through support.